# How to avoid prerender error in production build, vercel, next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I've been facing an issue for a few weeks now that is interrupting my learning and development. My project works fine in the dev environment, but I can no longer release it to production on Vercel. But I can't make it work, I've tried everything I found on the internet but I can't fix the project;

Before the code was a little different, the "find" method was inside getStaticProps, and it was giving me the error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')".

Worst of all is that anyway it was and is working in the dev environment

Now I'm facing the following error:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/produtos/Heróis". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Error serializing .produtos returned from getStaticProps in "/produtos/[categoria]".
Reason: undefined cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use null or omit this value.
```

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong. I'm losing my hair already.

github: https://github.com/oliveirabruno01/site_estilo_refactored (the error are ocurring in /produtos/[categoria] page)

**getStaticPaths:**

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
const res = await fetch('https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/categorias/json/&apikey=eda45968702e9e3ff10bb3dbd0fdd14286ecac428363231ed48271ad38fb7067b8578dbc');
const res_json = await res.json();
const categorias = res_json.retorno.categorias;

const paths = categorias.map(_categoria => ({
    params: {
        categoria: _categoria.categoria.descricao
    }
}));
return { paths, fallback: 'blocking' }
```

}

**getStaticProps**

```
export async function getStaticProps( {params} ) {
let categorias;
let produtos;

const categorias_res = await fetch('https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/categorias/json/&apikey=eda45968702e9e3ff10bb3dbd0fdd14286ecac428363231ed48271ad38fb7067b8578dbc');
const cat_json = await categorias_res.json();

const produtos_res = await fetch('https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/produtos/json/&apikey=eda45968702e9e3ff10bb3dbd0fdd14286ecac428363231ed48271ad38fb7067b8578dbc&imagem=S');   
const pro_json = await produtos_res.json();

categorias = cat_json.retorno.categorias;
produtos = pro_json.retorno.produtos;

console.log(categorias);

if (!categorias || !produtos || !nome) return {
    props: {categorias: [], produtos: [], nome: params.categoria}
}; 

return { props: {categorias: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categorias)), produtos: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(produtos)), nome: params.categoria}}
```

}

**page component**

```
export default function ProdutosCategoria( {categorias=null, produtos=null, nome=null} ) {

if (!categorias || !produtos || !nome) return <><h1>Something did wrong :/</h1></>; 

const f_item = categorias?.find((cat) => cat?.categoria.descricao == nome);
const item = f_item?.categoria;

return <>
    <Head>
    <title>Estilo Criação: { item.descricao }</title>
    </Head>
    <div id={styles.corpo}>
        <h1 className={styles.titulo}>Categoria { item.descricao }</h1>
        <br></br>
        
        <Row>
            {
        
                produtos?.map((_produto, i) => (
                    <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={3} xl={3} key={_produto.produto.id}>
                        <ProductsSingle item_data={_produto.produto} />
                    </Col>
                ))
            }
        </Row>
    </div>
</>
```

}

**ProductsSingle component:**

```
export default function ProductsSingle({item_data=null}){ 
const [num, setNum] = useState(1)

if (!item_data) return null;

return(
    <Link href={"/produto/" + item_data.descricao }>
        <div className={styles.produto} id={styles.delimitador}>
            <img src={item_data.imagem[num].link} onMouseEnter={() => setNum(3)} onMouseLeave={() => setNum(1)}/>
            <h4>{item_data.descricao}</h4>
            <h3 className={styles.preço}>R$ {Number.parseFloat(item_data.preco).toFixed(2)}</h3>
            <p>até <strong>3x</strong> de <strong>R$ {Number.parseFloat(item_data.preco/3).toFixed(2)}</strong> sem juros</p>
            <Button variant="success" className={styles.comprar}>Comprar</Button>
        </div>
    </Link>
)
```

}